# Same paths React Router Dom v6 and different outlet in each of them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to different routs in navigation and i dont know how to it
here is what i tried

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
 createRoutesFromElements(
  <>
    <Route path="/" element={<NavBar />}>
      <Route path="/" element={<LogIn />} />
      <Route path="/sign-up" element={<Signup />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />}>
      <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
    </Route>
  </>
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Within a single routes/router configuration you can't render more than one route per URL path you want to match.

Seems you *basically* want to conditionally render the `NavBar`, and `Login` and `HomePage` components based on some user "authentication state". For this I'd suggest creating a protected route component and does this conditional rendering, moving the `Login` component to its own route.

Example:

```
const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const isAuthenticated = /* auth context/state/etc */

  return isAuthenticated
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
      <Route element={<RootLayout />}>
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
      <Route element={<NavBar />}>
        <Route path="/login" element={<LogIn />} />
        <Route path="/sign-up" element={<Signup />} />
      </Route>
    </>
  ),
);
```

Comment: but now i can not run rootlayout and navbar togerther i want them to be run together

Comment: @TwanaKhudhur I suppose you could render one by the other, e.g. `RootLayout` renders `NavBar` and an `Outlet` for the nested routes. The code in your post doesn't appear to do this so it wasn't something I considered you wanting the code to do. Can you edit your post to clarify what the expected output should be?